# CoreTelephony - how to use headers - get something unique for SIM

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, core-telephony, msisdn

I'm trying to determent some info for a user over the carrier network. I have found the `CTSubscriber` and `CTSubscriberInfo` headers in the framework, but I can't find any documentation on how to use them.

I need to find any unique data that the carrier has given the user like phone number or MSISDN or anything else that is unique to that SIM. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't find any documentation is because much of Core Telephony consists of private APIs. Consequently, there isn't any way to access the SIM card from an app published on the App Store. A jailbroken device is, of course, another story, but in that case you're pretty much on your own.